# Convert a hex number to decimal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hex

I have something like the following:

```
92e1a330
3ff32343
4a443455
23d4df43
5323e345
```

I realised that Matlab is not able to read hex numbers using textscan so I read the whole text file as a string. The problem is that when I try to use hex2dec() to convert the string to hex, I don't quite get what I want. For instance, for `92e1a330` hex, `hex2dec` returns `2.4643e+009` instead of `2464260912`. Is it possible to fix that somehow? Thanks!

Comment: What about using 'cast' to convert the float to int?  Or if you are actually losing precision, hex2num instead of hex2dec

Comment: Cast worked great but hex2num didin't solve the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full number is there, just hidden behind the display formatting. For example:

```
num2str(hex2dec('92e1a330'))

ans =

2464260912
```

Comment: Thanks for that, worked great. I wander why you have to call both 'num2str' and 'hex2dec' to make it work but anyway, let it be...

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the way Matlab displays numbers, but the actual values are generally stored with more precision than it prints to the screen.

To adjust the display format, use the `format` command.  For example:

```
>> format short g  %This is the default
>> x = hex2dec('92e1a330')
x =
  2.4643e+009
```

Now set the format to a long format

```
>> format long g
>> y = hex2dec('92e1a330')
y =
            2464260912
```

Regardless, the numbers are the same

```
>> x-y
ans =
     0
```

There are a lot of format options, including display as hex, and display as engineering (like scientific, but the exponent is always a multiple of 3).  `help format` for more.

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, the number is there, but Matlab omits some digits due to the format setting.

A simple way is to force the result from hex2dec to be integer, and then all digits will show up. For example:

> > x = uint32(hex2dec('92e1a330'))

x =

2464260912